# Secure Boot is Unsupported while Bios Mode is set to UEFI on Lenovo T520 Laptop on System Information

Tags: bios, uefi, lenovo-laptop, secure-boot, windows-11

My Lenovo T520 laptop bios is set to UEFI and currently running Windows 10. Under System Information I can see UEFI for Bios Mode but Secure Boot is shown as unsupported. Does UEFI enable mean secure boot is enabled or there will be a separate setting under BIOS that I could not find? Also disk partition style is set to GPT, not sure if that will be any point to consider?

This will help me choose to plan Windows 11 Update on the laptop. Please suggest.

[image: System Information Under Windows 10]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Secure boot is an option in your system firmware that is independent of UEFI. You have to specifically enable secure boot in your firmware for it to be seen as "supported" by you system.

Having a GPT disk is normal under UEFI and implies your system is otherwise correctly set up for UEFI.

Your [processor is not on Microsofts support list](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-hardware/design/minimum/supported/windows-11-supported-intel-processors). As a result your system will not automatically update to Windows 11 and if you manually install then you may not receive feature updates or other key updates.

Comment: Thanks, @mukubai for your input. Appreciate it. I think the laptop T520 does not have an option for changing Secure Boot, still, I will google on the internet.

Comment: @Prabhat according to   https://help.1e.com/display/B2U14/Support+on+Lenovo+systems apparently the T520 does not support secure boot.

Comment: @Prabhat - I suspect the reason it does not support Secure Boot is that your device did not come with Windows 10. All Windows 10 OEM devices required Secure Boot support with the ability to disable and enable it.  Even if your device supported Secure Boot, your processor wouldn't have been supported, and I suspect your device does NOT support TPM 2.0